# Detecting an escaping Earth

Tags: science-based, earth, astrophysics

Suppose that, some day, for reasons, the Earth is mysteriously accelerated prograde until it reaches escape velocity. It then starts a trajectory that will take it off of the solar system. It might take a few centuries or millennia for us to actually exit the solar system, but in this specific case we would pass through Mars's orbit in two months, and Jupiter's in eleven months.

The acceleration happens for approximately twelve hours and then stops. No source of acceleration is detected, though - no stars, black holes nor anything else doing a flyby inside the solar system is ever noticed. Consider that the Earth is "magically accelerating on its own".

Once this mysterious event happens, when and how could we detect that we are on the way to leave the solar system? Suppose 2020 technology.

Comment: A prograde impulse won't cause the Earth to leave the Solar System, ever. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20249/deriving-the-changes-in-keplerian-elements-induced-by-small-impulses/20659

Comment: I don't know the figures but I expect astronomers will notice pretty quickly that the other planets and stars aren't quite where they should be and investigations will follow. Also I'd guess small unexpected changes in communication delay times with space probes would be noticed pretty soon too.

Comment: @Topcode if we accelerate the Earth at 1m/s2 for 3h21m40s we would reach escape velocity. That is approximately 0.1G, hardly harmful.

Comment: @Spencer if you reach escape velocity you do have a tendency to escape a system. And the impulse I intend to do here is hardly a small one (would increase Earth's orbital speed by around +30%).

Comment: The fact that things are getting pretty darn cold all of a sudden might be a clue

Comment: i must be really bad at math then

Comment: same day - any asteroid observation will be screwed almost immediately, immediate problems with connection to [deep space network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Deep_Space_Network), and sats there. moon is  accelerated too? it is not bound by gravity to the earth, in ~10ish hours its size will shrink twice of original, so as tides will be affected. soo, quite fast by all sorts of things

Comment: @Spencer Of course it will. Escape velocity is only a velocity, not a direction. As long as you're traveling at a body's escape velocity, you will never come back, regardless of where you're pointed. A prograde impulse will increase velocity, and if sustained, will at some point exceed the Sun's escape velocity.

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law 1m/s2 would be huge. It will cause hurricanes and giant tidal waves. For most of the Earth's surface, all structures that were vertical would become a "Leaning Tower of Pisa" - and many would not survive this challenge.

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law 1m/s2 is **10%** of the Earth's gravity. For comparison, Moon's gravity, which is responsible for most of our tides, manages to do it with a tiny **0.0003%** gradient on Earth surface.

Comment: @Alexander I'll take that into consideration - I had initially thought that a global acceleration would keep things intact. I might have to handwave that - or have the acceleration be smaller but over a longer span.

Comment: Ligo: "Calibration error!"

Comment: "or have the acceleration be smaller but over a longer span" - without inertia cancelation device on the volume enveloping the planet and its nearest orbit +200km at least - there is no way u move the planet without that, no matter which noticeable(1mm/ss as an example) acceleration you do. even a gravity beam maybe not good enough. on a planetary scale, the planet and its behavior to forces may be compared to a water balloon coated with a very thin glass layer.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw If Earth actually felt .1g acceleration there would be no survivors to notice it--that's far more than the Earth itself can take, the Earth would flow into a new shape that balanced the forces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Within a few minutes, when GPS goes out

The [Global Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System), and similar systems, such as the Russian [GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS), rely on very precise measurements of the distance between a receiver and several satellites.

The satellites are orbiting the Earth, but that doesn't mean that accelerations applied to Earth are applied to orbiting satellites. Unless the magic extends to them, their orbits relative to Earth will change, and GPS receivers will start to get confused.

Doing the sums, Earth needs to gain 12.3 km/sec of velocity over 12 hours. Call that an acceleration of 1km/sec per hour, or 1000/3600 = 0.27 metres/second/second, which is about 0.03g. Civilian GPS receivers will [cut out entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Restrictions_on_civilian_use) when Earth's velocity relative to where it should be reaches 500 metres/second, but that will take half an hour, and receivers will have been confused sooner than that.

Low-orbit satellites will also have been hitting the leading face of Earth for a while, but most of them won't be noticed.

Has the magician taken care to avoid Earth colliding with the Moon? That would rather spoil the effect.

Comment: I'd venture to say that the loss of low orbit satellites would also be noticed quickly because that's where all the communications satellites are.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan: the cellular communications satellites are in low orbit, but they aren't a big part of traffic as yet, AFAIK. Fibre optics handles most long-haul communications these days.

Comment: Satellite TV broadcasts (Dish Network, DirectTV), satellite telephony (Iridium), satellite internet providers (the upcoming Starlink constellation), broadcast video uplinks used by news satellite trucks, etc.  I agree that the total bandwidth is miniscule relative to fiber but a disruption would immediately noticed because the traffic tends to be realtime and/or high impact.

Comment: Solar escape velocity from earth's orbit is about 42 km/sec. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity So where did you get 12.3 km/sec?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: The OP specified "prograde," which I took to mean tangential to its orbit, in the direction it was moving at the moment the acceleration started. It already has 29.8 km/sec  of orbital velocity, so it only needs to add about 12.3 km/sec.

Answer (score 8):

**Probably very quickly.**

There's stargazers all over the world, as well as highly sensitive telescopes in space. A 24/7 observation of space is guaranteed. The change might seem minute, but this displacement can create huge discrepancies with the aiming of these telescopes as well as expected data that returns to us. We have apps that can show the position and names of stars and planets. This data comes from painstakingly created databases, all done with calculation and observations. If the planet has accelerated, we'll surely notice in the data. At first we might be confounded by this data and the conclusions, but realisation will set in pretty quickly.

Believing this realization might take longer though.

Comment: Ummm.... It will take **centuries** before star positions will change because of Earth drifting away from the sun. It will take MANY days before planetary positions will be noticeably off, even to good observatory-grade telescopes. You would notice the displacement of the sun, sooner.

Comment: @PcMan you're giving the same reasons in your own answer as in mine... you don't need two way communications for doppler effects or other effects to occur.

Comment: no. but you will notice a frequency-locked communications channel drifing off-sych a HELL of a lot sooner than you will notice that Mars is 0.00000000000000000001 arcsecond misplaced from where it should be. The first is immediate, dependant on relative velocity. The second requires a discrete amount of displacement to occur, which take a lot of time at interplanetary distances.

Answer (score 1):

We'll at least know that something significant is underway before the acceleration period is over. Solar escape velocity for Earth orbit is about 41.2 km/sec. By fortuitous coincidence, a 12-hour acceleration to this velocity will require an acceleration of just about 1 m/sec^2, or 1/10 g.

If "the earth accelerates" means just the rocky/metallic part, the result will be massive "tidal" effects as the ocean slops around to find a new equilibrium.

But I suspect you mean a "magical" acceleration field which encloses the earth and its inhabitants out to, let's say, the edge of outer space, or 100 miles altitude. Below this altitude, nobody feels a thing.

As has been mentioned, this means we shuck off our shell of satellites pretty quickly. However, it's not clear how well monitored their orbits are, or how long it would take to come up with an explanation for their loss. There will be clue to found (when someone notices it) that about half of the satellites will reenter and be destroyed, and  half will appear to accelerate away from us - all in the same direction.
This applies to LEO satellites such as the mentioned GPS constellation and a good few others. For the geosync communications satellites the situation will depend on the acceleration vector. If the acceleration occurs in the plane of the ecliptic, we'll only get a few reentries, since the orbital plane of such satellites is tilted with respect to the ecliptic, due to being aligned with the equator, which is tilted with respect to ecliptic. Most will be left behind. If the acceleration is pointed along our poles, we'll slide out of the ring of geosyncs. Their orbits will all be perturbed in the same way, resulting in a circularly symmetric collection of new paths (not orbits, as we'll leave them behind at this acceleration), and in this case that might be the big clue as to what is going on.

What would be pretty obvious would be losing the moon. By the end of the acceleration period, we'll have shifted position just about 1 million kilometers - and the orbit of the moon has a radius of about 400,000 km. So it will be obvious to astronomers that something really strange is happening by no later than 6 hours into the event.

If we move directly away from the moon, it will appear to recede from us at about 1 m/sec^2, and by the end of the acceleration period will appear to be only 40% of its normal size and constantly shrinking. People will notice this sort of thing.

Of course, it's entirely possible that nobody will figure out what happened. Ever. If we're really unlucky, the new path of the earth will intersect the moon's orbit when the moon is in the wrong place. The resulting collision will destroy all life on earth and end the investigation.

Comment: "However, it's not clear how well monitored their orbits are," When *every GPS device on the planet* stops working, it will be pretty clear immediately that something is going wrong.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - Sorry for the confusion. I'm fully aware that the very fast degradation of GPS service will raise red flags in a hurry. By "monitored" I mean observed in such a fashion that their apparent orbits can be determined.

Answer (score 1):

If just the Earth is accelerated, then we would be inundated by a rain of low orbit satellites impacting the atmosphere. Almost immediately, on the order of 10 minutes time.

If the **Earth and its surrounding space out to past and including the Moon gets uniformly accelerated**, then we would very soon (also order 10 minutes) start losing communications with the many solar system probes we have out there, as their aim will be slightly off and their communications will be ever so slightly dopplered away from the correct frequencies. The various space agencies will detect this dopplering (they can detect a relative speed difference in Voyager of 5cm/hour, if they are trying to communicate with them.)

They will definitely have accurate information on the Earth's new position and speed within the first day.
How long until they BELIEVE that, and it becomes public notice?  Weeks, easily!